# Can't add a new field to res.company odoo 8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

M using odoo 8 running on windows, i inhereted the res.company model, and added few columns

```py
class res_ company(models.Model):
   _name = "res.company"
   _inherit = "res.company"
    manager_name = fields.Char()
```

but it when i restart odoo, i receive the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: column res.company.manager_name does not exist
LINE 1: ...mpany"."paperformat_id","res.company"."sale_note","res.compa...
```

isn't possible to add a new field to res.company or what exactly ?

Comment: After adding the column did you update the module?

Comment: And also check your .py file name given in _init_.py

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem, i had to update the base module, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal you can update your base and it solves the problem
Cmd : Python odoo-bin -c  -d  -u base

It takes time to update so be patient